# Value in Datagrid itemrenderers set data method doesn't return the correct data

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I've got a Gridcolumn in a Datagrid (Spark). The Column's dataprovider is a Number value that gets updated via Binding.

Now, without an item renderer the cell displays the correct values.
If I set an item renderer, I can't access the values in this renderer.

My renderer looks like this, so nothing really do here (for now) but to trace the value, but the value is always NaN.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%" >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
            trace(Number(value));
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

I don't really understand why this happens, so any insight would be much appreciated! Again, without the renderer, the column displays the correct values, so apparently the DefaultGridItemRenderer works fine.

As requested, here is my Datagrid;

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{_listItems}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="change" headerText="Change" itemRenderer="myitemrenderer" />
    ...
</s:DataGrid>
```

_listItems is an ArrayList with instances of a model class, which has (amongst others) a property called change of type Number.

Comment: try with `<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer/>`

Comment: Throws the following error: VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.controls.dataGridClasses::DataGridListData could not be found.

Comment: Can you add your DataGrid code? It would be easier to tell if we could see how you assign dataprovider and item renderer for that column.

Comment: If you put breakpoint in your `set data` function and debug, what is the value of value parameter? is it null? It should be Object, so how can you expect `Object` to be casted to `Number`

Comment: Yes, it is Object, of type myModel to be exact. What I'm after is the property (change), which is a Number, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
        [Bindable]
        private var simpleDataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{first: "this", second: "is", third:"test", fourth:"data"}, 
            {first:"not", second:"full", third: "row"}]);
```

DataGrid:

```
<s:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{simpleDataProvider}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="first"/>
            <s:GridColumn itemRenderer="Group.TestRenderer3"/>          
            <s:GridColumn dataField="third"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fourth"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:columns>        
</s:DataGrid>
```

And item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                lblData.text = value.second;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Most important thing is `value.second` in your case it should be `value.change`

Comment: That's the problem, I can't do it like that since the DataGrid has variable columns and the model class has a huge amount of properties that can be displayed in the grids columns, so working with fixed values here (like the change) isn't possible.